# Can't find where the overflow is coming from CSS

Tags: css, overflow, slideshow

Hello my wonderful CSS friends! So, today I am having a problem with a slideshow not showing up from some sort of overflow problem that I can't find. I know it is the overflow because when I change it to "visible" the slideshow appears, but my content background disappears and I cannot figure out why this is happening, at all. I have done extensive research on this site and others trying to find a similar problem, but I can't seem to find anything similar.

Here is the code to explain things a little bit more:

CSS for the content:

```
#body {
background:none #000;
margin-top:21px!important;
}
#body.home {
border:1px solid #4f4f4f;
margin:0 auto;
width:1100px;
}
#body.home div:first-child {
overflow:hidden;
}
#body.home div:first-child div:first-child {
border-bottom:0px solid #4f4f4f;
border-right:1px solid #4f4f4f;
float:left;
padding:0 0 13px;
width:510px;
}
#body.home div:first-child div:first-child h2 {
margin:13px 0 0 20px;
}
#body.home div:first-child div:first-child h2 a {
color:#fff;
font-family:oswaldregular;
font-size:18px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
line-height:18px;
margin:0;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#body.home div:first-child div:first-child p {
color:#a5a5a5;
font-size:14px;
line-height:18px;
margin:16px 0;
padding:0 30px 0 20px;
}
#body.home div:first-child div:first-child p a {
color:#a5a5a5;
font-style:normal;
margin:0;
text-decoration:underline;
}
#body.home div:first-child div:first-child a {
color:#af0000;
font-size:14px;
font-style:italic;
line-height:18px;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#body.home div:first-child div:first-child a:hover {
color:#ff0000;
text-decoration:none!important;
}
#body.home div:first-child ul {
border-bottom:1px solid #4f4f4f;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
}
#body.home div:first-child ul li:first-child {
border:none;
}
#body.home div:first-child ul li {
border-left:1px solid #4f4f4f;
float:left;
width:auto;
}
#body.home div:first-child ul li h3 {
margin:23px 0 5px 20px;
}
#body.home div:first-child ul li span {
color:#a5a5a5;
display:block;
font-size:14px;
line-height:18px;
margin:1px 0 24px 20px;
}
#body.home div:first-child ul li a img {
border-top:1px solid #4f4f4f;
}
#body.home div {
border-bottom:none;
overflow:hidden;
}
#body.home div div:first-child {
border-bottom:none;
border-right:0px solid #4f4f4f;
float:left;
width:510px;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul {
border-bottom:none;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li:first-child {
width:238px;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li {
border-right:1px solid #4f4f4f;

padding:0;
width:239px;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li a {
display:block;
float:none;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li a img {
border-bottom:1px solid #4f4f4f;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li h4 {
margin:9px 30px 0 20px;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li h4 {
color:#fff;
float:none;
font-size:14px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:700;
line-height:18px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li p {
color:#a5a5a5;
font-size:14px;
line-height:18px;
margin:1px 30px 0 20px;
}
#body.home div div:first-child ul li p a {
color:#a5a5a5;
display:inline;
float:none;
font-style:normal;
margin:0;
text-decoration:underline;
}
#body.home div div {
float:left;
width:510px;
}
#body.home div div h3 a {
color:#FFF;
font-family:oswaldregular;
font-size:18px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
line-height:18px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#body.home div div ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#body.home div div ul li {
border-top:1px solid #4f4f4f;
overflow:hidden;
}
#body.home div div ul li a {
display:block;
float:left;
margin:0 20px 0 0;
}
#body.home div div ul li a img {
border-right:0px solid #4f4f4f;
}
#body.home div div ul li div {
width:298px;
}
#body.home div div ul li div span {
color:#a5a5a5;
display:block;
font-size:11px;
line-height:18px;
margin:11px 0 0;
}
#body.home div div ul li div h4 {
color:#fff;
float:none;
font-size:14px;
line-height:16px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#body.home div div ul li div p {
color:#a5a5a5;
font-size:14px;
line-height:18px;
margin:2px 0 0;
}
#body.home div div ul li div p a {
color:#a5a5a5;
display:inline;
float:none;
margin:0;
text-decoration:underline;
}
#body.home div div ul li div p a.more {
color:#AF0000;
display:inline;
float:none;
font-size:14px;
font-style:italic;
line-height:18px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#body.home div div ul li div p a.more:hover {
color:#ff0000!important;
text-decoration:none!important;
}
```

The code that controls the overflow I am working with is the third one down:

```
    #body.home div:first-child {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

This is the only one that makes any changes when I change it to visible.

And here is the CSS for the slideshow:

```
#slider {
position: relative;
width: 500px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

#slider .viewer {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider .viewer .reel {
display: none;
height: 500px;
}

#slider .viewer .reel .slide {
position: relative;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}
```

Finally, here is the html for the content:

```
<div id="body" class="home">
    <div>
        <div><br><br>
            <h2><a href="index.html">Welcome to our site!</a </h2>
            <p>
                Text. Text. Text. Text. 
            </p>
            <a href="services.html">Read More</a>         </div>

            <div id="slider">
                <div class="viewer">
                    <div class="reel">

                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img1.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title="" /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img2.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title="" /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img3.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title="" /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img4.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title="" /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img5.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title="" /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img6.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title="" /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img7.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title=" " /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img8.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center"  title="" /></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="/images/img9.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="center" title="" /></div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>

</div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#slider').slidertron({
                viewerSelector: '.viewer',
                reelSelector: '.viewer .reel',
                slidesSelector: '.viewer .reel .slide',
                advanceDelay: 6000,
                speed: 'slow'
            });
        </script>
```

If you can see where there would be any overflow anywhere on the slideshow, can you please let me know, because I have been looking at this code for days now and I cannot see where there would be any overflow anywhere. Argh!

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, I should do that. Give me a few minutes and I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I tried to recreate it in fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/wc6QE/21/, but for some reason the pictures I am using (just some random cat pictures) aren't showing up with this code when I put it on visible and I can't figure THAT one out. Hahaha. Oy vey. I have it on hidden right now, but when you change the first overflow to visible, the background disappears and on my real site the actual slideshow shows up. I don't know what I did differently here.

Comment: I know that pictures are showing up on fiddle by themselves, though because when I just put the img src in the pic shows up http://fiddle.jshell.net/3fEhd/.

Comment: Images can create overflow because they are inline elements. Change CSS so that 'img' is 'display:block;'

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but 'img' was already coded as 'display:block'. I changed the slider's display to block in hopes that that might work, but unfortunately, it did not work. I do appreciate the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED IT! The div div was floating to the left and so I tried changing the float to 'none' and there we are. The background popped right up behind everything. I have to keep the overflow to visible still for the slideshow to show up, but as long as I have the background and the slideshow, I don't mind. I don't anticipate any problems with this as it is a static page. I want to thank everybody for the time and and suggestions that they offered. Have a wonderful rest of the weekend!